# How can I fix the ERR_SSL_CIPHER_OPERATION_FAILED error while installing React packages with create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs

how fixed react create problem

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code ERR_SSL_CIPHER_OPERATION_FAILED
npm ERR! errno ERR_SSL_CIPHER_OPERATION_FAILED
npm ERR! Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/@typescript-eslint%2Fparser: 702C0000:error:1C800066:Provider routines:ossl_gcm_stream_update:cipher operation failed:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\providers\implementations\ciphers\ciphercommon_gcm.c:320:
npm ERR!

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Ravi Joshi\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-05-30T07_40_06_671Z-debug-0.log

Aborting installation.
npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting proj/ from E:\react Course
Done.

trying to create new react project